# trying to set the size of a SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, skspritenode, cgsize

(Sorry for my english)

I have a SKSpriteNode:

```
let button = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 50));
```

It should have a width of 50 px and a height of 50 px but it takes all the screen:

[image: skspritenode taking the whole screen]

If I println button.size.width I get 50

Why is my skspritenode taking the whole screen?

Comment: What is the position of spritenode ?

Comment: Did you add it as sub-node that is your screen background?

Comment: The position is: (0, 0) and to add it to the view I do: self.addChild(self.button)

Comment: Have you checked the size of the scene?